# Reuse xml layout but override src and text attributes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a static layout file, let's say something like :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/some_drawable" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/placeholder_error_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="something"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to be able to reuse this layout file multiple times throughout my application but change the text & src attributes according to each usecase.

I don't want to duplicate the layout files and a custom View for this seems overkill. Is there a solution in the framework for this ?

Comment: you need to get the ImageView and the TextView then change the values just like you would any layout

Comment: I would like to directly inflate the layout with the final values :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would abandon the `LinearLayout` concept – you can go easily with the `TextView` only.

Move all global attributes to style

```
<style name="TextWithImage">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">24dp</item>
</style>
```

And in your layouts use this `TextView` with overriden text and drawable

```
<TextView
    style="@style/TextWithImage"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/some_drawable"
    android:text="something" />
```

This does not have any disadvantages over `<include>` AFAIK. The only issue is you dont have full control over the image size, but if your drawables have 56dp (and they should) you are completely fine.

Comment: " but if your drawables have 56dp (and they should)" why 56 and why they should?

Comment: He was manually setting the `ImageView` size to 56dp originally. If you want to display an image of fixed size, it is helpful if the resource already has the size. and doesn't need to get scaled.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are inflating this layout in your Activity's `onCreate()`. You will need to get a reference to the ImageView and TextView in your code after the layout is inflated, and then you can call methods on them.

First, add an id to the ImageView: `android:id="@+id/image`.

Then, in your Java code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    // get references
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder_error_info);

    // set properties
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_drawable);
    textView.setText("something");
}
```

You can replace the calls to setImageResource and setText with anything you like. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah that's one solution but I am actually looking for a way to do that without using setters, simply by overriding the attributes read by the view in its constructor.

Comment: Hm, I guess it would technically be possible if you created a theme overlay for each specific use case and set it in `android:theme`, but this will only work on Lollipop and above. The natural way to do this in Android is via code. Is there a particular reason you don't want to do this via code?